# How would the thickness of the electrode affect the resistance of the circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, material-science

Imagine a portion of the circuit is completed by gluing two electrodes on the opposite walls of the inside of a rectangular tube and submerge the tube in salt water, would the thickness of the electrode affect the resistance of the circuit? Like, if the "electrode" is made of copper tape instead of a copper strip like we usually see, would it change the resistance of the circuit?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the resistance would depend on the area of each electrode which is exposed to the water.